# Python code runs through cmd however not in IDLE..Why?

Tags: python, cmd, python-idle, command-line-interface

Okay so i just got my leap motion device and im trying to run the scripts. When I press f5, the scripts load however it doesnt do the functions.. (it initilizes, loads everything) .

But when i open by double clicking (through cmd) it works how its supposed to properly..

Any idea why?

Here is an example code:

http://pastebin.com/6Pu2DQ4n

Comment: Can you show some code? We can't help you if we don't know what's wrong in the code.

Comment: THeres nothing wrong with the code, its just doesnt run fully when running by pressing f5, it does with cmd. ill add the source here anyway

Comment: You have to assume that 99% the problem is always in the code. The programming language itself won't have many glitches so it must be a problem in your code.

Comment: Its not the code.. considering the program is working how it is supposed to... Just doesnt through the IDLE.

Comment: you are probably using two different versions of python.

Comment: Im using python 2.7.3, got no others installed :S

Answer (score 1):

IDLE isn't executing the code in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` due to the way it is expected to work.

Change the last two lines so that the `if` statement isn't there, and the `main()` call is not indented:

```
# if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Note, this *will* mean that `main()` is executed *every* time this function is imported anywhere, but it should run in IDLE. (IDLE didn't run `main` previously as it doesn't trigger the `if`)

PS Well done on getting hold of a LEAP! V. jealous >:)